# CONSULTA UNON EN ACCES CUANDO HAY MAS COLUMNAS EN UNA DE LAS TABLAS

Tags: ms-access-2010

Tengo una BBDD Access, quiero realizar una consulta de unión de dos consultas, pero las dos consultas no tienen el mismo numero de columnas,
la idea es crear nueva columna con el nombre que falta y así ya estarían iguales, pero esta no lo acepta ya que no esta en la tabla principal.
hay alguna forma de realizarlo mediante SQL u otra forma?
Un saludo

Comment: No es necesario que las tablas tengan el mismo número de columnas para realizar una consulta.

Comment: Pero al ser de unión (UNION ALL) me da este error "El numero de columnas de las dos tablas o consultas seleccionadas para una consulta de unión no coincide"

Comment: Por favor, añade las tablas y la consulta EN tu pregunta para poder darte una respuesta concreta

Answer (score 1):

ya he visto como se hace,en la ayuda de access, he puesto como primera tabla1  la que mas columnas tenia, y todos los nombres de las columnas ordenado por el mismo nombre para poder localizar las que me faltan, después en la la tabla2 lo mismo, pero como faltaban columnas se añadido (NULL,) por cada columna, ahora están todas y no da error.
Ejemplo: si son dos los que faltan

SELECT
nombretablaoconsulta1.columna1,
nombretablaoconsulta1.columna2,
nombretablaoconsulta1.columna3,
nombretablaoconsulta1.columna4,
nombretablaoconsulta1.columna5,
nombretablaoconsulta1.columna6
FROM nombretablaoconsulta1

UNION ALL

SELECT
nombretablaoconsulta2.columna1,
nombretablaoconsulta2.columna2,
nombretablaoconsulta2.columna3,
nombretablaoconsulta2.columna4,
NULL,
NULL
FROM nombretablaoconsulta2

Listo, estas columnas como no están, no aparen.

Un saludo a todos.
y gracias.